# Can someone explain to be what is going on here? existential universal quantifications

Tags: universal, existential-type, quantifiers

I have to program (C++) and find the true value of the following. I am uncertian as to what it exactly means.

```
AxAy(C(x, y) -> ((Aw(C(x, w) -> w = y) ^ (Az(C(z, y) -> z = x))
```

note that the -> is an implication, C(x,y) is a function/ Predicates, ^ is the and function, A is the universal. if it helps, C(x,y) is the predicate, x calls y

I boiled it down using the Implication definition and arrived at `AxAy -C(x,y)` where - is the negation.
is this correct? is the whole long original statment a complicated way of saying " no one made any calls" ?

Answer (score 0):

Using your interpretation for `C(x,y)`, this first order sentence means that if `x` calls `y` and `w`, then `w = y`. That is, `x` calls at most one element. Similarly, If `y` is called by `x` and `z`, then `z = x`. That is, `y` is called by at most one element.

I'm not sure what you meant by writing a C++ program for finding the true value of this sentence. I'm assuming your program receives a set of pairs `(x,y)` representing the pairs for which `C(x,y)` is true. If that is the case, you just have to check if there are no two pairs in the set that violate the conditions above. That is, there are no pairs `(a, b)` and `(a, c)` in the set, and there are no pairs `(a, b)` and `(c, b)`.